# Odd Stack on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The site I'm currently working on is here: https://integrityjourney.org.

The theme is a little on the difficult side.  I have written somewhere around 1100 lines of custom code.

I used a shortcut (bad) of using an online mobile design viewer and found that while it looks great on those previews, on actual mobile devices, it's stacking like so:

[The problem in general, white space on the right side of the screen, with a few rows going into the white space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdU4U.jpg)

[Bottom half of page showing a row going fullscreen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXTXk.png)

The theme is called Evont. WPBakery comes packaged with it.  This is actually a plea out of frustration. I have looked at everything for so long, I just can't see where the problem might be.  I am sure it is something simple...I'm probably code-fried.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that these `divs` are bigger (wider) than the actual screen. There's just too much going on with these weird margins and the rest. Besides fixing the dimensions, an immediate fix would be adding `overflow-x: hidden` to `body`:

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I will give that a shot...never even thought of overflow....thank you!

Comment: @RyanFlynt Glad to help! If it solves your problem, consider marking the answer as "accepted" (check mark).